# Java 8 Streams - Grouping a stream of tuples

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Edit:: I am rephrasing the question so that its more clear

I have written this code

```
    List<ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>>();
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(1, 1));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(1, 1));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(1, 1));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(2, 2));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(2, 2));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(2, 2));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(3, 3));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(3, 3));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(3, 3));
    Stream<ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>> stream = list.stream();
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
       ImmutablePair::getLeft,
            Collectors.mapping(
                    ImmutablePair::getRight,
                    Collectors.summingInt(Comparator.comparing(ImmutablePair::getRight))
            )                
    ));
```

I want to process this list using steams so that the output is a map which contains keys (1, 3), (2, 6), (3, 9)

So basically, we group on the left item of the tuple and then sum the right item.

This code does not compile and the compiler says that it cannot resolve getLeft, getRight methods.

Here are the error messages from the compiler

```
/Users/abhi/JavaProjects/MovieLambda2/src/main/java/com/abhi/MovieLambda2.java:229: error: method summingInt in class Collectors cannot be applied to given types;
                            Collectors.summingInt(Comparator.comparing(ImmutablePair::getRight))
                                      ^
  required: ToIntFunction<? super T#1>
  found: Comparator<Object>
  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#2,U exist so that Comparator<T#2> conforms to ToIntFunction<? super T#1>
  where T#1,T#2,U are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>summingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,U>comparing(Function<? super T#2,? extends U>)
    U extends Comparable<? super U> declared in method <T#2,U>comparing(Function<? super T#2,? extends U>)
/Users/abhi/JavaProjects/MovieLambda2/src/main/java/com/abhi/MovieLambda2.java:229: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
                            Collectors.summingInt(Comparator.comparing(ImmutablePair::getRight))
                                                                      ^
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      no suitable method found for getRight(Object)
          method Pair.getRight() is not applicable
            (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
          method ImmutablePair.getRight() is not applicable
            (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T,U are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in method <T,U>comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>)
    U extends Comparable<? super U> declared in method <T,U>comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>)
/Users/abhi/JavaProjects/MovieLambda2/src/main/java/com/abhi/MovieLambda2.java:229: error: invalid method reference
                            Collectors.summingInt(Comparator.comparing(ImmutablePair::getRight))
                                                                       ^
  non-static method getRight() cannot be referenced from a static context
  where R is a type-variable:
    R extends Object declared in class ImmutablePair
/Users/abhi/JavaProjects/MovieLambda2/src/main/java/com/abhi/MovieLambda2.java:228: error: invalid method reference
                            ImmutablePair::getRight,
                            ^
  non-static method getRight() cannot be referenced from a static context
  where R is a type-variable:
    R extends Object declared in class ImmutablePair
/Users/abhi/JavaProjects/MovieLambda2/src/main/java/com/abhi/MovieLambda2.java:226: error: invalid method reference
                    ImmutablePair::getLeft,
                    ^
  non-static method getLeft() cannot be referenced from a static context
  where L is a type-variable:
    L extends Object declared in class ImmutablePair
```

Comment: You should post a simple example demonstrating the problem, otherwise it is difficult for us to reproduce it.

Comment: What about just Collectors.groupBy(ImmutablePair::getLeft) ? I mean separately. Does it also fail?

Comment: You're trying to group instances of ImmutablePair by using a reference  to a method of Movie. That can't possibly work. That's like sorting persons by the color of a banana. You can sort people by their height or their weight or their age, but not by a property of a banana. We could explain what the exact error message means if you posted the exact error message instead of paraphrasing it and giving your own, incorrect understanding of the message. We could help you fix the code if you posted the classes involved.

Comment: I have rephrased my question and simplified the example. Now it should be clear.

Comment: Why are you using `Comparator.comparing()`? From your new example, I can't understand what you are comparing and why you need this comparison in order to sum the values of each group.

Comment: Now it's absolutely different question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** this answers an original question ([revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32680310/2)). New question is well answered by @Shiraaz.M.

---

Your `Comparator` accepts a pair, thus you need to call `getRight` with `Collectors.mapping`:

```
Map<String, Optional<Movie>> map = ml.getDataAsStream()
    .<ImmutablePair<String, Movie>>flatMap(x -> x.getGenre()
            .map(g -> new ImmutablePair<String, Movie>(g, x)))
    .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                ImmutablePair::getLeft,
                Collectors.mapping(ImmutablePair::getRight, 
                    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getVoteCount)))
            ));
```

Note that depending on compiler used you may need to specify some types explicitly as automatic inference may fail.

Actually such scenarios are well supported in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which enhances standard Java Streams. The same result can be achieved writing this:

```
Map<String, Optional<Movie>> map = StreamEx.of(ml.getDataAsStream())
    .cross(Movie::getGenre) // create (Movie, Genre) entries
    .invert() // swap entries to get (Genre, Movie)
    .grouping(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getVoteCount)));
```

Finally note that using `maxBy` collector you'll have `Optional` values which is useless as they cannot be empty. For `maxBy/minBy` scenarios it's better to use `toMap` collector with custom merging function:

```
Map<String, Movie> map = ml.getDataAsStream()
    .<ImmutablePair<String, Movie>>flatMap(x -> x.getGenre()
            .map(g -> new ImmutablePair<String, Movie>(g, x)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(ImmutablePair::getLeft, ImmutablePair::getRight, 
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getVoteCount))));
```

Or using StreamEx:

```
Map<String, Movie> map = StreamEx.of(ml.getDataAsStream())
    .cross(Movie::getGenre)
    .invert()
    .toMap(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getVoteCount)));
```

Comment: I think my previous example was a little complex. so I

Comment: This did not work. I implemented the suggestion above. but I still get compiler message `cannot resolve getLeft`

Comment: Out of interest, what does invert() do?

Comment: @JohnMcClean, [swaps key and value](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#invert--) in key-value pair.

Comment: Thank you so much... this is a wonderful answer. Sorry for changing my initial question. many people were telling me that its not clear what I am asking so I tried to simplify my question.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your ImmutablePair class looks like this (this class might need to be static depending on whether the sample code was executed from within a main method):

```
class ImmutablePair<T,T2> {
    private final T left;
    private final T2 right;

    public ImmutablePair(T left, T2 right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;

    }

    public T getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public T2 getRight() {
        return right;
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me:

```
List<ImmutablePair<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(1, 1));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(1, 1));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(1, 1));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(2, 2));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(2, 2));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(2, 2));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(3, 3));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(3, 3));
    list.add(new ImmutablePair(3, 3));
    Map<Integer, Integer> collect = list.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                ImmutablePair::getLeft,
                Collectors.summingInt(ImmutablePair::getRight)));

    System.out.println(collect);
```

And the result is:

> {1=3, 2=6, 3=9}

**The possible problem**

The problem is in this section of code:

```
        Collectors.mapping(
                ImmutablePair::getRight,
                Collectors.summingInt(Comparator.comparing(ImmutablePair::getRight))
        )
```

The Collectors.mapping collector first adapts an object of type T into and object of type U and then runs a collector on type U. ([That's the gist of the javadoc for me](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-))

So what you're doing is something like:

- Transform ImmutablePair into an Integer.
- The 2nd parameter is now a Collector that expects an Integer type, but you are "using an ImmutablePair type". Additionally, the Comparator.compare() returns a Comparator and you're looking to return an Integer type. So to fix your exact line of code is to change it to something like:

> Collectors.mapping(ImmutablePair::getRight, Collectors.summingInt(Integer::valueOf))

But you don't need this because you can simplify this by calling Collectors.summingInt directly:

> Collectors.summingInt(ImmutablePair::getRight)